# How to create Stacked Column Chart with different colors and custom tooltips in a stack?

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to use Google Visualization to create a stacked column chart with two series per column. Essentially, I'm presenting data on some tanks, and the lower part of each column displays information about the volume currently in the tank, and the upper part displays information on the remaining volume to fill the tank.

I want to be able to set the color and the tooltip separately for both parts of each column, but I have been unable to find a solution. Here's my current example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart', 'controls']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
function drawDashboard() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Element');
data.addColumn('number', 'FillRate');
data.addColumn('number', 'PotentialFill');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRow(['Tank1', 60, 40, "blue", "Some tooltip"]);

var chartchart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
chartType: 'ColumnChart',
containerId: 'chart0',
dataTable: data,
view: { columns: [0,1,2,3,4],  },
options: {
title: 'Tanks', tooltip: { isHtml: true }, legend: 'none', vAxis: { textPosition: 'out', title: '% Filled', maxValue: 100, minValue: 0 }, hAxis: { textPosition: 'out', title: 'Tanks' }, isStacked: true
}});
chartchart0.draw();    }
</script>
```

I've tried setting two style columns, but it only seems to affect the top of each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results you want by adding some more columns for additional tooltips and styles, and removing the `view:` setting in the options.

here is a fiddle that looks like what you want, http://jsfiddle.net/c5nwt1n4/1/
and code below!

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
function drawDashboard() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Element');
data.addColumn('number', 'FillRate');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addColumn('number', 'PotentialFill');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRow(['Tank1', 60,  "color:green", "Filled up",40, "color:blue", "could be filled"]);

var chartchart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
chartType: 'ColumnChart',
containerId: 'chart0',
dataTable: data,
options: {
  title: 'Tanks',
  tooltip: { isHtml: true },
  legend: 'none', 
  vAxis: {        textPosition: 'out', title: '% Filled', maxValue: 100, minValue: 0 },
  hAxis: { textPosition: 'out', title: 'Tanks' },
  isStacked: true
}
});
chartchart0.draw();    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I look at the jsfiddle I see a red and green column, not red and blue as would be expected from the code. Also the "could be filled" tooltip doesn't show. The style and tooltip seem to only be effecting the bottom of the column.

Comment: Sorry, sort of new to using fiddles. just updated it!

Comment: It seems to be really important that someone would need to specify custom tooltip for every number column, once you choose the custom tooltip route.